# Android Wait Until An Image Has Loaded To the ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have problem that scroll through images on disk which are rather large (about 1 Mb each) Now the problem I have is not the latency between each image but rather that while loading the image the scroll of the image (which I use to signal a change) keeps being detected while the image is loaded resulting in a moved image when it finally loads. My question is simple. Is there a way to wait until the image is loaded (that way I can block screen commands until the image is completely loaded).

Thanks for any answers!

PD: By the way I'm loading the pages in an ImageView;

EDIT:

Posting AsyincCode:

This is in my test activity itests.java

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void > {
    private final ProgressDialog Loading = new ProgressDialog(itests.this);

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Loading.setMessage("Loading...");
        Loading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            pvm.setPages(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void... params){
        if (Loading.isShowing()){
            Loading.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Now pvm is my PageViewManager (PageView is my Custom ImageView that receives all my touch events)

Here is what it does:

```
public void setPages(String left, String center, String right){
    //if (!timer.isAlive()){
        Left = left;
        Center = center;
        Right = right;
        DoublePageMode = true;
        toggleDoublePageMode();
        System.err.println("Waiting...");
        //centerPage.blockCommands();
        //timer.start();
    //}
}

@Override
public void toggleDoublePageMode(){
    if (DoublePageMode){
        //Going into Normal View
        threePageLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        leftPage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams cll = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DWidth,DHeight);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams zero = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,DHeight);
        centerPage.setImage(Center, DWidth, DHeight, PageState.NORMAL);
        centerPage.setLayoutParams(cll);
        leftPage.setImage(Left, DWidth, DHeight, PageState.NORMAL);
        leftPage.setLayoutParams(zero);
        rightPage.setImage(Right, DWidth, DHeight, PageState.NORMAL);
        rightPage.setLayoutParams(zero);
        DoublePageMode = false;
    }
    else{
        DoublePageMode = true;
        threePageLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        leftPage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams cll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DWidth,DHeight,1f);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams zero = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DWidth,DHeight,1f);
        centerPage.setImage(Center, DWidth, DHeight, PageState.TWOPAGEMODE);
        centerPage.setLayoutParams(cll);
        rightPage.setImage(Right, DWidth, DHeight, PageState.TWOPAGEMODE);
        rightPage.setLayoutParams(zero);            
    }
}
```

The @Override notation is because the function also has to be called from the PageView on a LongTouch. However I'm not doing any sort of long press so it's not a problem. Since the AsyncTask tries to move the layout of the activity showing the images I get the error I told you, which makes perfect sense.

When I need to call this method It comes from this code (on itests.java):

```
public void movePages(boolean next) {       
            //Code that initializes left,center,right
            new ImageLoader().execute(left, center, right);
}
```

This method is called by the PageViewManager (pvm) through an inteface.

I hope this gives you an idea!

Thank you very much!

EDIT2:

I've solved it! Actually more like I found a way around it but I works beautifully!

All I did is create a Timer class that lets me know when a certain time has passed. When I need to load the images I start it (it is another thread) and set a boolean that makes my pages ignore touch events (by returning false in onTouchEvent). When it is done it call a function in my pvm that simply set that boolean again to true and the effect is just what I wanted. The timer waits for only about 500 miliseconds.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Could you specify which container you are using to scroll the ImageViews?

Comment: I actually Load 3 images in custom containters derived froma a ImageView into a horizontal LinearLayout. As the user scrolls to the right or left one I have to load 3 Images. It works fine and the latency is very acceptable. I just need to ignore touch events until all loading is done.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your using a aSyncTask to load the data! You could simply add a progress dialog whilst loading the data. this can be done by adding:

```
pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Data", "Please Wait...", true);
```

before you start loading the data, then once all your data is ready simply call `pDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: Sorry I've tried two different way of using an AsyncTask but it just doesnt work the program keeps on crahing because "06-26 10:18:42.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24041): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
"

Comment: post your code and i'll take a look for you, if not i've got a sample that shows how to setup a aSyncTask link: https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BwAnjRVwT4WzOWMwYjFhNTctOTUxYy00NjQwLTgwNWEtMmE5MzEyZWQ3NjUx&hl=en_US&authkey=CLnH8_ID

Answer (score 0):

One (longish) solution I can think of is to implement your own ImageView class, which loads a BitmapDrawable and draws it in onDraw(). This way, you can know for sure when onDraw() completes, and call a different callback (e.g. onDrawComplete() ) to toggle touch event handling.

Comment: It wasn't long as I allready was extending my ImageView. However doing this makes everything very laggy (understandable as I have to decode the image and show it every time I touch the screen). Thank you anyways it was a really good option.

Comment: You can decode and save the data for later re-use. Also, do it in a new thread.

Comment: But If I do it in a new thread I'll have the same problem as before. This problem is because the setImageBitmap and setImageDrawable do so in a new thread. How can I know when the thread is finished without polling?